# DataProvider = ProviderFactory.GetProvider("") NullReferenceException?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I am getting a NullReferenceException when SubSonic calls the default contructor for my database.

In my case the line it errors on is.

DataProvider = ProviderFactory.GetProvider("MDMA");

I have the namespaces set correctly and the classes seam to be getting generated correctly, so it looks like I can connect to the database.  Is this a bug?

I am using version 3.0.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code requires a connection string in your execution environment with a name "MDMA".

Comment: Thanks Rob, for the quick reply.  I had the connection string setup in my app.config, but I think I pulled the trigger to fast when adding a new app.config and accidentally put it in a non executing projects.  The app.config was actually included in a library project in the same solution.

After I moved it, all is working.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Connection String in the App.Config/Web.Config file with a name "MDMA".

**Example:**

```
    <add name="MDMA" connectionString="Data Source=[DS];Initial Catalog=[Database];MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Id=[UID];pwd=[PWD]" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```